# receiving char * from UART of AVR

Tags: c, avr, uart

I want to receive a string(pointer to characters) by UART using ATMEGA16. I burned this code on the kit then I used hyperterminal (realterm) and made a test to input a string ("on") and if it is received then portc (LEDS) will be set to 1 but it doesn't work ... anyone!? :D

Implementation of functions

```
#include <avr/io.h>

#define F_CPU 8000000UL
unsigned char *x;

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

void uartinit()
{
    UCSRB |= (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN);   
                    // Turn on the transmission and reception circuitry
    UCSRC |= (1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ0) | (1 << UCSZ1); 
                    // Use 8-bit character sizes

    UBRRL = BAUD_PRESCALE; // Load lower 8-bits of the baud rate value..
                           // into the low byte of the UBRR register
    UBRRH = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8); // Load upper 8-bits of the baud rate value..
                                  // into the high byte of the UBRR register
}

void uartsend( unsigned char *data )
{
    while(*data != '\0')
    {
        /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
        while ( !( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)) );
        /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
        UDR = *data;
        data++;
    }


    while ( !( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)) );

    UDR = *data;

}

unsigned char * uartrecieve()
{
    //unsigned char i=0;
    //    unsigned char * x;

    /* Wait for data to be received */

    //    char * ptr = &UDR;

    while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)) );

    while(UDR != '\0')
    {
        *x = UDR;
        x++;
        while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)) );
    }
    *x = UDR;

     return x;
}
```

and this is main function

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "UARTInterface.h"


int main(void)
{
    DDRC=0xFF;
    uartinit();
    while(1)
    {
        unsigned char *y;
        y=uartrecieve();    
        if(strcmp(y,"on")==0)    
        {
            PORTC=0xff;

        }
        //uartsend(y);
        //TODO:: Please write your application code 
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, the built-in clock on the AVR is not accurate enough for proper serial comms.  You really should use a properly matched crystal for the clock.  I would suggest reading [AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=45341) and do some searches on there, as that site is 100% dedicated to AVR, and has many examples, articles.  Also, see [this article](http://www.github.com/abcminiuser/avr-tutorials/blob/master/USART/Output/USART.pdf?raw=true)

Comment: First problem, you need to receive the data into an array - not a pointer.

Comment: @Old The build in clock works fine. Also mocj is right.

Comment: To clarify what @mocj is saying, the string comparison is guaranteed to fail. x is globally defined to be a pointer somewhere in memory. (It will probably be pointing into your interrupt table.) You fill up that location, advancing x, then return the last position x points to. That location will contain the character '\0', not 'n'. You need to allocate an array to hold the data, and set x to point to the start of the receive function. Do the string comparison against the start of that array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

**1.** You're not allocating any space for the received characters. You have a global `unsigned char *x` (which is not initialised) that you dereference and assign values to, then increment - this is just overwriting random positions in memory.

You should instead assign some space by creating an array from the calling function (`main` in this case) and passing a pointer to `uartreceive` along with the size of the buffer

```
unsigned char y[20]; // in main
unsigned char len;
len = uartreceive(y, 20);
...
```

Then (note this is untested)

```
unsigned char uartrecieve(unsigned char *x, unsigned char size)
{
    unsigned char i = 0;

    if (size == 0) return 0;            // return 0 if no space

    while (i < size - 1) {              // check space is available (including additional null char at end)
        unsigned char c;
        while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)) );  // wait for another char - WARNING this will wait forever if nothing is received
        c = UDR;
        if (c == '\0') break;           // break on NULL character
        x[i] = c;                       // write into the supplied buffer
        i++;
    }
    x[i] = 0;                           // ensure string is null terminated

    return i + 1;                       // return number of characters written
}
```

Each time you call this function, it will overwrite the previous contents of rx_buffer so make sure you are finished using it first. Read up on arrays, pointers and strings if you're not certain what's happening here.

Better yet would be to pass in a pointer to `uartreceive` so that the calling function can supply the area of memory

**2.** It is unlikely that your serial terminal software will be sending NULL terminated strings by default (i.e. with '\0' at the end), normally it would send a new-line ('\n') character. I believe realterm can do this, but it's worth checking.

**3.** Reading from UDR will clear the RXC flag, allowing the AVR to write another character into UDR, so reading from UDR twice in a row is probably a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

UBBRL must be written AFTER UBRRH to ensure atomic operation (ie : copy full 16 bits of ubrr AT THE SAME TIME on baud rate divisor.
This is indicated on ATMega doc (for example ATMEGA16 doc http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc2466.pdf  page 168) :

*Writing UBRRL will trigger an immediate update of the baud rate prescaler*
Atmel example are written this way

```
void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr){
/* Set baud rate */ 
UBRRH = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
**UBRRL = (unsigned char)ubrr;**
/* Enable receiver and transmitter */
UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
/* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<USBS)|(3<<UCSZ0);
}*
```

When you write the wrong order (UBRRH last), UBRRH is not updated until the next UBRRL write. Doesn't mater most of the time as UBRRH = 0 the most of the time (until BAUD > 100bit/s)